# Combinatorics of two pairs in poker

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

I've read the answer on counting the number of possible two pair hands in poker and I understand it. However, I don't know why my initial approach was wrong. Can someone point to the flaw in my approach.

Here's my logic. I'm going to assume a hand in the particular order XXYYZ, and then divide by 5! to account for the fact that the order of cards can be in any order.

The first card X is any one of the 52 cards.
The second card X is any one of the remaining 3 cards that would make the initial pair XX.
The third card Y is any one of the 48 cards remaining in the deck that's not X.
The fourth card Y is any one of the remaining 3 cards that would make the second pair YY.
The fifth card is any one of the 44 cards remaining in the deck that's not X nor Y.

So my answer is: (52*3*48*3*44)/(5!)

This doesn't even end up as an integer. So where did my logic go wrong?

Comment: What if your first card were $5 \diamondsuit$ and second card $5 \clubsuit$... or they were in the reverse order?  How would you count those?

Comment: Although I assume an order of the cards initially, I thought dividing by 5! would make the count be of any order.

Comment: Nope.  For the $XX$ you must divide by $2!$... and likewise for the $YY$.  And what if your cards appeared $YYZXX$?  You must figure out all these orders to get your answer.

Comment: Much easier to pick the two paired ranks, $\binom {13}2$, pick the two suits within each rank, $\binom 42^2$, and then pick the odd man out, $44$.

Answer (score 1):

If order matters, you should multiply (not divide) by 5! You generate all possible permutations from a set of different elements.

However, David G. Stork's comment is still legit:

5♢5♠6♣6♡J♣ will generate all permutations including 5♢5♠6♣6♡J♣

6♡6♣5♠5♢J♣ will generate all permutations including 5♢5♠6♣6♡J♣

So, each permutation will be counted 8 times (2!×2!×2!). One 2! comes from permutation inside the first pair, one 2! comes from the second pair and one 2! from permutations between pairs (we could have selected 6 first and 5 second).
The number of tuples containing two pairs is then:
$$n=\frac12\frac{52\times3}2\times\frac{48\times3}2\times44\times5!=14\,826\,240$$

If we divide by total number of tuples (52!/47!), we will get the probability of two-pair hand:
$$p=\frac{n}{52!/47!} = \frac{198}{4165}\approx 4.75\,\%$$

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.